# VB how to parse string contents

Tags: vb.net, windows, excel

I have some code that I have hacked about and is part of a bigger script and I am slowly getting to do what I want, but also understanding what it is doing at the same time but I am having an issue with a String and outputting the content into separate cells

```
DIM objWMIService, objItem, colItems
DIM strDriveType, strDiskSize, csv

SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
SET colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3")
csv = "Drive, Size (GB), Used (GB), Free (GB), Free(%)" & vbcrlf
FOR EACH objItem in colItems

DIM pctFreeSpace,strFreeSpace,strusedSpace

pctFreeSpace = INT((objItem.FreeSpace / objItem.Size) * 1000)/10
strDiskSize = Int(objItem.Size /1073741824) & "Gb"
strFreeSpace = Int(objItem.FreeSpace /1073741824) & "Gb"
strUsedSpace = Int((objItem.Size-objItem.FreeSpace)/1073741824) & "Gb"
csv = csv & objItem.Name & vbtab & strDiskSize & vbtab & strUsedSpace & vbTab &    strFreeSpace & vbtab & pctFreeSpace & vbcrlf

objXLApp.Sheets("OA Summary").Range("D7").Value = (CSV) 

'objXLApp.Sheets("OA Summary").Range("D7").Value = (objItem.Name)
'objXLApp.Sheets("OA Summary").Range("E7").Value = (strDiskSize)
'objXLApp.Sheets("OA Summary").Range("F7").Value = (strUsedSpace)
'objXLApp.Sheets("OA Summary").Range("G7").Value = (strFreeSpace)
'objXLApp.Sheets("OA Summary").Range("H7").Value = (pctFreeSpace)
```

The "CSV" value when directly to a Txt file and works quite well and is expected.

```
Drive   Size    Used    Free    Free(%)
C:          97Gb    67Gb    29Gb    30.7
D:          367Gb   312Gb   55Gb    15
E:          465Gb   256Gb   209Gb   44.9
R:          149Gb   8Gb     141Gb   94.2
```

But when I try put this into excel I cannot separate the Cells I get the above in a single cell. If I uncomment the `objXLApp` sheets I only get one row, which in my case is the R Drive.

Any help is greatly fully received and appreciated!

Comment: Where is the `Next` for `For Each`? On the other hand, you could open the text file in excel (as CSV file).

Comment: Hi shahkalpesh, the Excel document is open and being populated further up in the script and is on screen

Answer (score 0):

When you un-comment the code for the deposits, you need to move down the rows using something like:

```
Dim I As Long
I = 6
For Each objItem In colItems
I = I + 1
objXLApp.Sheets("OA Summary").Range("D" & I).Value = (objItem.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,  when i try that I code I get "Expected end of statement" on the "Dim I As Long" on Character 9 which is the start of "AS Long"

Comment: I then get "invalid 'for' Loop control Variable" on  "in colItems" but im a bit confused as that works fine further up ?

Comment: We need to get the appropriate syntax for **vb.net** v.s. **VBA**

Comment: Then ignore my coding until you get to **VBA**

Comment: sorry for the confusion not notepad++, I use the trial VBSedit (www.vbsedit.com), sorry I use notepad++ for making quick code changes but VBSedit is the main editor I use

Comment: I have played about with the code and got the following to work, but it only shows me the Drive letters though .................................Next 
  Dim I
  I = 6
   For Each objItem In colItems
   I = I + 1
   objXLApp.Sheets("OA Summary").Range("D" & I).Value = (csv)